# How to set inactive tabs indicator style for react navigation material top tabs v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to set inactive tabs indicator style for react navigation v5 material top tabs?

Active one can be set like this:

```
tabBarOptions={{
  indicatorStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
}}
```

Comment: The indicator is always shown with the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

tabBarOptions={{
     activeTintColor: tintColor,
     inactiveTintColor: defaultColor,
}}

Try to customized tabs using this. It described there.

Comment: how can i modify style ex. opacity